# Cas Client Ticket Vlidation failed with error No subject alternative DNS name matching cas URL found

Tags: java, filter, single-sign-on, cas

We are using CAS version 5.0 and LDAP authentication with DUO multi-factor authentication. Cas server working fine. then We are started to integrate the CAS SSO in our applications that time the We are facing a issue in java CAS client.
Client application successfully redirects to CAS when the user is not logedIn.and the user authenticated the user and redirect to the client application. but at the time of Client application ticket validation filter throwing an error with this log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching URL found.
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:458)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching URL found.
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:442)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching URL found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 41 more
```

we are using this filtters in for authentication those are give below

```
<filter>   
     <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>   
     <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
      <async-supported>true</async-supported>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
         <param-value>${CAS_PREFIX_URL}</param-value>
     </init-param>

  </filter>    
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
      <param-value>${CAS_PREFIX_URL}login</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>serverName</param-name>
      <param-value>${SERVER_NAME}</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas10TicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
      <param-value>${CAS_PREFIX_URL}</param-value>
    </init-param>
<!--     <init-param>
      <param-name>serverName</param-name>
      <param-value>${SERVER_NAME}</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>redirectAfterValidation</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>exceptionOnValidationFailure</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
 -->
   </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally indicates that the CAS server and the client in question here do not trust each other's certificate; specifically, it seems like the certificate issued to the CAS server does not have a valid subject alternative DNS name matching URL found.

You may use the below command to create a keystore and a keypair with a valid subject DNS:

`keytool -genkey -alias cas -keyalg RSA -validity ... -keystore /etc/cas/thekeystore -ext san=dns:$REPLACE_WITH_FULL_MACHINE_NAME`

Or if you have created the keystore and certificates using any other means, you need to make sure the SAN DNS field is populated.